# How can I track that the user closed the rewarded video without watching it to the end? (IronSource)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ironsource

I am using IronSource and cannot see how I can track that the user closed the rewarded video without watching it to the end. I need this for analytics, I have to send an event in the case when the user has not watched the rewarded video to the end, but closed it and did not receive a reward for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement rewarded video events, as described here: https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/unity/rewarded-video-integration-unity/

You need those events:

```
void Init()
{
    // IronSource initialization code

    // add callbacks to events;
    IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAdClosedEvent += RewardedVideoAdClosedEvent; 
    IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent += RewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent;
} 

void RewardedVideoAdClosedEvent()
{
}

void RewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent(IronSourcePlacement ssp)
{
}
```

If I understand correctly, ad closed can be fired even if ad was closed with reward, so you need to implement logic to filter analytic events in this case.

Comment: closed and rewarded events are asynchronous

Comment: yes, but it's all ironSource provides. You can fire an analytic event for every reward video start (or end) and for every reward get. The difference between amount of those events will be amount of ads that were closed without reward

Comment: but there can be situation when close event will be fired before rewarded event

Comment: Do you really need to monitor events at realtime? Usually you check analytics at the end of the day/week/month

Comment: Oh, yes, I understand what you mean. You can do this. But we do not track in analytics that the video has started.

Comment: I think that's the only workaround you have, to begin track those event too, because of how ironSource works.